# Crash log in iOS App which I can't trace

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash

I have been suffering to trace the crash I am getting on the actual device (iPhone/iPad) in my Universal App without being able to identify the cause of that crash. It is been couple months now and no progress has been done. I have attached the crash log from my iPhone. Please help I am getting depressed from this pain!

```
Incident Identifier: D6FFC0E5-5917-4161-8153-2507856ACCD2
CrashReporter Key:   d450bd4a17cb7225884a2117b0c26a006dbd284b
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Survey [118]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1346F760-3D6E-4C77-B1C0-1D979AC174E7/Survey.app/Survey
Identifier:      Survey
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-04 14:03:27.686 +0300
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  14

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3285929e 0x3a58197a 0x33160368 0x3281b308 0x3281b458 0x327a0134 0x327ada9a 0x324fe318 0x324fe892 0x324fcb42 0x324fc998 0x324fc8fc 0x324fc7d0 0x324fc6a8 0x3a99f134 0x3a99ce8c 0x3a99cdbc 0x3a99d918 0x3a99dabc 0x3a9cda0c 0x3a9cd8a0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6eeb4 0x3aa6e000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f048 0x3aa6e000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                
0x3282e040 0x32797000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                
0x3282cd5a 0x32797000 + 613722
4   CoreFoundation                
0x3279feb8 0x32797000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                
0x3279fd44 0x32797000 + 36164
6   GraphicsServices              
0x363782e6 0x36373000 + 21222
7   UIKit                         
0x346b52fc 0x3465e000 + 357116
8   Survey                        
0x0002cf6a 0x2b000 + 8042
9   Survey                        
0x0002cf24 0x2b000 + 7972

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f648 0x3aa6e000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99f974 0x3a997000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99f654 0x3a997000 + 34388

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6eeb4 0x3aa6e000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f048 0x3aa6e000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                
0x3282e040 0x32797000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                
0x3282cd9e 0x32797000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                
0x3279feb8 0x32797000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                
0x3279fd44 0x32797000 + 36164
6   WebCore                       
0x387b3500 0x387a9000 + 42240
7   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6eeb4 0x3aa6e000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f048 0x3aa6e000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                
0x3282e040 0x32797000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                
0x3282cd9e 0x32797000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                
0x3279feb8 0x32797000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                
0x3279fd44 0x32797000 + 36164
6   Foundation                    
0x330ec3d0 0x330bf000 + 185296
7   Foundation                    
0x3316fe80 0x330bf000 + 724608
8   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
9   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f594 0x3aa6e000 + 71060
1   CoreFoundation                
0x328321f2 0x32797000 + 635378
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
3   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f08c 0x3aa6e000 + 69772
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d0d2a 0x3a9c7000 + 40234
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d0aa0 0x3a9c7000 + 39584
3   JavaScriptCore                
0x3676ec70 0x36713000 + 375920
4   JavaScriptCore                
0x36880552 0x36713000 + 1496402
5   JavaScriptCore                
0x36892fa8 0x36713000 + 1572776
6   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
7   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f08c 0x3aa6e000 + 69772
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d0d2a 0x3a9c7000 + 40234
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9daf14 0x3a9c7000 + 81684
3   JavaScriptCore                
0x36813f3c 0x36713000 + 1052476
4   JavaScriptCore                
0x36813e7c 0x36713000 + 1052284
5   JavaScriptCore                
0x36892fa8 0x36713000 + 1572776
6   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
7   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6eeb4 0x3aa6e000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f048 0x3aa6e000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                
0x3282e040 0x32797000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                
0x3282cd9e 0x32797000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                
0x3279feb8 0x32797000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                
0x3279fd44 0x32797000 + 36164
6   WebCore                       
0x3884dd02 0x387a9000 + 675074
7   JavaScriptCore                
0x36892fa8 0x36713000 + 1572776
8   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
9   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f08c 0x3aa6e000 + 69772
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d0d2a 0x3a9c7000 + 40234
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9daf14 0x3a9c7000 + 81684
3   JavaScriptCore                
0x3676ec42 0x36713000 + 375874
4   WebCore                       
0x389c7e88 0x387a9000 + 2223752
5   WebCore                       
0x389c7e3c 0x387a9000 + 2223676
6   JavaScriptCore                
0x36892fa8 0x36713000 + 1572776
7   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f08c 0x3aa6e000 + 69772
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d0d2a 0x3a9c7000 + 40234
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9daf14 0x3a9c7000 + 81684
3   CoreMedia                     
0x32d858ac 0x32d82000 + 14508
4   MediaToolbox                  
0x33877e56 0x33874000 + 15958
5   CoreMedia                     
0x32da3890 0x32d82000 + 137360
6   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
7   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.remote
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6eeb4 0x3aa6e000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa6f048 0x3aa6e000 + 4168
2   MediaToolbox                  
0x3387e0b4 0x33874000 + 41140
3   CoreMedia                     
0x32da3890 0x32d82000 + 137360
4   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d830e 0x3a9c7000 + 70414
5   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9d81d4 0x3a9c7000 + 70100

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7fd98 0x3aa6e000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cdcf6 0x3a9c7000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cda12 0x3a9c7000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cd8a0 0x3a9c7000 + 26784

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7fd98 0x3aa6e000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cdcf6 0x3a9c7000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cda12 0x3a9c7000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cd8a0 0x3a9c7000 + 26784

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7fd98 0x3aa6e000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cdcf6 0x3a9c7000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cda12 0x3a9c7000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cd8a0 0x3a9c7000 + 26784

Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue
Thread 14 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        
0x3aa7f350 0x3aa6e000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9f611e 0x3a9c7000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3aa3296e 0x3a9c7000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib               
0x39fd0d4a 0x39fcd000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib               
0x39fcdff4 0x39fcd000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib               
0x3a581a74 0x3a579000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib               
0x39fce078 0x39fcd000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib               
0x39fce110 0x39fcd000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib               
0x39fcf50e 0x39fcd000 + 9486
9   libobjc.A.dylib               
0x3a5819ba 0x3a579000 + 35258
10  Foundation                    
0x33160368 0x330bf000 + 660328
11  CoreFoundation                
0x3281b30a 0x32797000 + 541450
12  CoreFoundation                
0x3281b458 0x32797000 + 541784
13  CoreFoundation                
0x327a0134 0x32797000 + 37172
14  CoreFoundation                
0x327ada9a 0x32797000 + 92826
15  CFNetwork                     
0x324fe318 0x324ae000 + 328472
16  CFNetwork                     
0x324fe892 0x324ae000 + 329874
17  CFNetwork                     
0x324fcb42 0x324ae000 + 322370
18  CFNetwork                     
0x324fc998 0x324ae000 + 321944
19  CFNetwork                     
0x324fc8fc 0x324ae000 + 321788
20  CFNetwork                     
0x324fc7d0 0x324ae000 + 321488
21  CFNetwork                     
0x324fc6a8 0x324ae000 + 321192
22  libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99f134 0x3a997000 + 33076
23  libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99ce8e 0x3a997000 + 24206
24  libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99cdbc 0x3a997000 + 23996
25  libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99d91a 0x3a997000 + 26906
26  libdispatch.dylib             
0x3a99dabc 0x3a997000 + 27324
27  libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cda0e 0x3a9c7000 + 27150
28  libsystem_c.dylib             
0x3a9cd8a0 0x3a9c7000 + 26784

Thread 14 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3c548534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x28df0000      r6: 0x2d52adc4      r7: 0x28defac4
    r8: 0x2d52ada0    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0003ff01
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x28defab8      lr: 0x3a9f6123      pc: 0x3aa7f350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x2b000 -    0x95fff +Survey armv7  <4700be0bad463aee81e9745d5b9d3e18> /var/mobile/Applications/1346F760-3D6E-4C77-B1C0-1D979AC174E7/Survey.app/Survey
0x2fe0b000 - 0x2fe2bfff  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3178d000 - 0x3185efff  RawCamera armv7  <8752cce31e8e3ceab5d88c84e3481db2> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x31867000 - 0x31970fff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <a31ea5c288c6353f9d6c75cf37c10fae> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x3197a000 - 0x31a60fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31a61000 - 0x31a61fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31a62000 - 0x31ba0fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31ba1000 - 0x31c84fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31c85000 - 0x31f3afff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31f3b000 - 0x31f94fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31f95000 - 0x31fa6fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31fa7000 - 0x31fa7fff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31fa8000 - 0x31fb9fff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x31fbb000 - 0x3201ffff  AddressBook armv7  <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32020000 - 0x320dafff  AddressBookUI armv7  <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x320db000 - 0x320e9fff  AssetsLibrary armv7  <9a3a4a47a77833eb82a28757a3488660> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x32225000 - 0x324adfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x324ae000 - 0x32573fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32574000 - 0x325cafff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x325de000 - 0x32796fff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32797000 - 0x328c9fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x328ca000 - 0x32a02fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32a04000 - 0x32a3ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32c23000 - 0x32c3efff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32c3f000 - 0x32cf4fff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x32cf5000 - 0x32d4dfff  CoreLocation armv7  <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32d82000 - 0x32de7fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32de8000 - 0x32e70fff  CoreMotion armv7  <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32e71000 - 0x32ec7fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32ec8000 - 0x32f2afff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32f2b000 - 0x32f3afff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32f3b000 - 0x32feffff  EventKit armv7  <99a7a1603323319f9e24f97e9f89bfd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x330bf000 - 0x33282fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3343d000 - 0x33486fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33487000 - 0x3365ffff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33660000 - 0x336d8fff  MapKit armv7  <027e730f45cc3868b98833546bb55449> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x336d9000 - 0x33873fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <ce97a30e514d3a17ae93ba4a9d1d69d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x33874000 - 0x33aeefff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33aef000 - 0x33b75fff  MessageUI armv7  <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33b76000 - 0x33bcffff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33bfc000 - 0x33cbdfff  GLEngine armv7  <b3fd8a93778b317fab8630340a2d741b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x33cbe000 - 0x33cc5fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x33cc7000 - 0x33cc7fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33cc8000 - 0x33ccafff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <761c0f0e263c3d39adbb5bf789cedde1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x33ccb000 - 0x33ccdfff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33cce000 - 0x33cd2fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33cd3000 - 0x33d10fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33d11000 - 0x33e36fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <0b3cb1b9a5003c4a975ec268cabca3fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3440b000 - 0x34520fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34521000 - 0x3456efff  QuickLook armv7  <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3456f000 - 0x3459dfff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3459e000 - 0x3460bfff  Social armv7  <7b778c6ce3433df18ef0892acd831208> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x3461c000 - 0x3465bfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3465c000 - 0x3465dfff  Twitter armv7  <ecae25ed2c893a969ceb0b911420c2be> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x3465e000 - 0x34bb2fff  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34bb3000 - 0x34bf1fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34c09000 - 0x34c1dfff  QuickTime Plugin armv7  <ffbf866e28b036ac856b991b56abfef9> /System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin
0x34e87000 - 0x34e93fff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34eda000 - 0x34eddfff  ActorKit armv7  <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x34edf000 - 0x34ee2fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34fcb000 - 0x34fdefff  AirTraffic armv7  <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x34fdf000 - 0x352ebfff  Altitude armv7  <d507155292c8341395d2cbde05ae448d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
0x3530e000 - 0x35349fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3534a000 - 0x3536efff  AppleAccount armv7  <c54536fbc0f235f693060be33d4d4749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x3537b000 - 0x35388fff  ApplePushService armv7  <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x353bc000 - 0x353c5fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x353c6000 - 0x353dffff  AssistantServices armv7  <9608ae74229e3daeab9c8fcf679de7d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x353f5000 - 0x3540cfff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x35416000 - 0x3543afff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3544d000 - 0x3547cfff  BulletinBoard armv7  <9f46015c5d263064901f7725f4bb93e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x354ba000 - 0x354c1fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x354c2000 - 0x3558cfff  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35599000 - 0x3559dfff  CertUI armv7  <ce979f715cdb3cb5a0f7935f14cc0b35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x35643000 - 0x3565cfff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <ec2f76b3ac723a39bbf3f122d7fe73cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x35670000 - 0x35675fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x356fa000 - 0x3572afff  ContentIndex armv7  <00ed488e47ee34ca9f01f2cc911f453c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x357a6000 - 0x3588efff  CoreMediaStream armv7  <828bf27fe7a3337cbff7dd8837508819> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x3593b000 - 0x3593cfff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x359a4000 - 0x359a8fff  CoreTime armv7  <5f0b123555f03d8aa76cc54314907942> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x359a9000 - 0x359aefff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x359af000 - 0x359ebfff  DataAccess armv7  <d7185042adf63908ae87fe4a5c3f8a6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35b80000 - 0x35b92fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x35ba6000 - 0x35bbbfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <58352df07a0139de878e5e275e27ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x35bbd000 - 0x35bd0fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <331c11e50793340f9ce758435c9420ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x35bd1000 - 0x35bd2fff  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x35bd5000 - 0x35beefff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x35bf6000 - 0x35c0efff  EAP8021X armv7  <6d5ab53850e23fe389e64e2705bd7810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35c1e000 - 0x35c22fff  FTClientServices armv7  <6354e5b30919340db3b976312b284fce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x35c23000 - 0x35c60fff  FTServices armv7  <89c066d12a6031038a9b8c61221abc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35c61000 - 0x36074fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x360c1000 - 0x360c6fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <4366fa0d1a0938a794bd8346e286d6f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x3626c000 - 0x36278fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x36279000 - 0x36372fff  GeoServices armv7  <edbf37a31a6a31f49e392ed8ece200c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36373000 - 0x3637efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x363ed000 - 0x36468fff  HomeSharing armv7  <280b77b71df23f1cb5c9a2b76fc53212> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x36469000 - 0x36473fff  IAP armv7  <a9554a91bbb9308f96fcd9fddf596275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3652b000 - 0x365a3fff  IMCore armv7  <d5f1d98ec53d3acbb51b116e93923d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x3666a000 - 0x366b6fff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x366bd000 - 0x366befff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x366bf000 - 0x366c4fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x366c5000 - 0x366c9fff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36713000 - 0x368b9fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x368ea000 - 0x36920fff  MIME armv7  <57a1db0d5d3237708f54b3bd83553bae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x36921000 - 0x36957fff  MMCS armv7  <7f329f193ef138c2b372e8b16e855bce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x3695f000 - 0x36969fff  MailServices armv7  <a688a9972cb43169a19d2f2f57121a1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x36985000 - 0x369ddfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x369de000 - 0x369e3fff  Marco armv7  <da45fc9b228b3d1fad95e03071441585> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x369f4000 - 0x36a6afff  MediaControlSender armv7  <9fb205b64b5333a495ac61c149e0304b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x36a6b000 - 0x36a74fff  MediaRemote armv7  <73da55e989e73cb9ad6e9fdd4604ecc3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x36a75000 - 0x36a89fff  MediaStream armv7  <86443ae270083a829e1797d24cd0d17c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x36ae7000 - 0x36ba0fff  Message armv7  <f6684c79e78f371fa81c6ec7336a0701> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36ba9000 - 0x36babfff  MessageSupport armv7  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to symbolicate the crash report is pretty easy using Xcode organizer, you just need to drag into it (device tab). For more there is an [Apple Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html). 
After that we can understand better the crash.

Answer (score 0):

In your XCode Debugger Console :

```
di -s 0x3a58197a
```

Execute the above command. You'll get the Class where your app crashed. If you don't get it here. Try to change the memory address with your following trace. Use one at a time in your XCode Debugger.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3285929e 0x3a58197a 0x33160368 0x3281b308 0x3281b458 0x327a0134 0x327ada9a 0x324fe318 0x324fe892 0x324fcb42 0x324fc998 0x324fc8fc 0x324fc7d0 0x324fc6a8 0x3a99f134 0x3a99ce8c 0x3a99cdbc 0x3a99d918 0x3a99dabc 0x3a9cda0c 0x3a9cd8a0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rushi. I am a bit confused here as to execute the above command in the Debugger Area of Xcode. Can you please guide me through it. Thanks a lot for the big help.

Comment: @Sam when your app crashes just go on di -s 0x3a58197a giving this command in debugger area. It'll give you the class and line where your app is crashing.